# Java: JUnit, Inheritance & @15db9742?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, output

This is a simple Java app that calculates a departments monthly expenses, by summing the monthly wages of all the staff in that department.  A department's staff are arranged in a **hierarchy:** *(testers paid **500.0**, &, developers paid **1000.0**, are under a manager paid **300.0**, under a manager paid **300.0**).*

- managerA <-- managerB <-- tester1 &  dev1

In this way, the total value of expenses for ManagerA should be **2100.0**. This totaled expense is the departments monthly expense.

It was my intention to build an app that did this & then proved it by testing the return of **getTotalExpenses()**, which should be **2100.0**.

I Built the test, test failed([pic](http://screencast.com/t/CkOSJEfjJE)):

- java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2100.0> but was:<300.0>

So I built a **main()** with lots of **println()** to see what was going on & got some very unexpected output([pic](http://screencast.com/t/Myx7lZ5n)):

```
monDepExpensesApp.QATester@15db9742
monDepExpensesApp.Developer@6d06d69c
monDepExpensesApp.Manager@7852e922
monDepExpensesApp.Manager@7852e922
monDepExpensesApp.Manager@4e25154f
monDepExpensesApp.Manager@4e25154f
```

All of the documented **source code** is below, it explains much.

But these are my **questions:**

- Why didn't my test past? Am I not testing correctly or is my app flawed?
- Why did my main() display the above output?  Is it something like pointers, unsigned data, byte? Do I need to wrap, change data type?

I've never seen anything like this from Java.

Note: *I only build the main to tell me more about why my test failed.* 
Note: *The second question has been answered*

Thank you for taking a look, i'll be interested to see what you come-up with.

**Employee**

```
package monDepExpensesApp;

/**
 * Employee declares expenses, & getExpenses().
 * 
 * Employee is the superclass of Manager, QATester, and Developer.
 * 
 * @author Reed
 */
public class Employee {
    protected double expenses;

    /**
     * getExpenses() returns the monthly allocation amount of a Manager, Developer, or QATester object.
     * @return a double values representing what the specified Employee is paid each month.
     */
    public double getExpenses() {
        return expenses;
    }
}
```

**Developer**

```
package monDepExpensesApp;

/**
 * Developers warrant a monthly allocation of $1000.00, per Developer.
 * 
 * Developer extends Employee.
 * 
 * @author Reed
 */
public class Developer extends Employee {

    /**
     * Developer() creates a Developer, who is paid $1000.0 a month.
     */
    public Developer() {
        expenses = 1000.0;
    }
}
```

**QATester**

```
package monDepExpensesApp;

/**
 * QA Testers warrant a monthly allocation of $500.00, per QA Tester.
 * 
 * QATester extends Employee.
 * 
 * @author Reed
 */
public class QATester extends Employee {

    /**
     * QATester() creates a QA Tester, who is paid $500.0 a month.
     */
    public QATester() {
        expenses = 500.0;
    }
}
```

**Manager**

```
package monDepExpensesApp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Managers warrant a monthly allocation of $300.00, per Manager.
 * 
 * A manager is at the top of a hierarchical relationship,
 * in which one manager oversees employees such as developers,
 * QA testers, & other managers. A hierarchy is constituted of all the 
 * employees of a department. An employee's title is associated with
 * an amount paid monthly. A departments monthly expenses can be determined 
 * by adding the amounts paid to the employees in a hierarchy.
 * 
 * Manager extends Employee.
 * 
 * @author Reed
 */
public class Manager extends Employee {
    private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Manager() creates a Manager, who is paid $300.0 a month.
     */
    public Manager() {
        expenses = 300.0;
    }

    /**
     * Add() adds employees to a list.
     * @param employee
     */
    public void add(Employee employee) {
        employeeList.add(employee);
    }

    /**
     * getTotalExpenses() adds the values in employeeList,
     * calculating a departments total monthly expenses.
     * @return the value of totalExpenses.
     */
    public double getTotalExpenses() {
        double totalExpenses = 0.00;

        for(Employee employee : employeeList) {
            totalExpenses += employee.getExpenses();
        }
        return totalExpenses;
    }
}
```

**DepOneExpTest**

```
package monDepExpensesApp.UnitTest;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import monDepExpensesApp.Developer;
import monDepExpensesApp.Manager;
import monDepExpensesApp.QATester;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * DepOneExpTest evaluates a departments actual total expenses,
 * by comparing them to a projected total.
 * 
 * @author Reed
 */
public class DepOneExpTest {

    /**
     * testOne() compares a departments actual total expenses with a projected total of $2100.00.
     * This departments employees create the following hierarchy:
     * managerA <-- managerB <-- tester1 &  dev1.
     */
    @Test
    public void test() {
        QATester tester1 = new QATester(); 
        Developer dev1 = new Developer(); 

        Manager managerB = new Manager(); 
        managerB.add(tester1);
        managerB.add(dev1);

        Manager managerA = new Manager();
        managerA.add(managerB);

        assertEquals(2100.0, managerA.getTotalExpenses(), 0.001);
    }

}
```

**Main2**

```
package monDepExpensesApp;

public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QATester tester1 = new QATester();
        System.out.println(tester1);

        Developer dev1 = new Developer(); 
        System.out.println(dev1);

        Manager managerB = new Manager();
        System.out.println(managerB);

        managerB.add(tester1);
        managerB.add(dev1);
        System.out.println(managerB);

        Manager managerA = new Manager();
        System.out.println(managerA);

        managerA.add(managerB);
        System.out.println(managerA);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to override `toString()` on your classes. The `Object.toString()` method is being called and since you are not overrding it, it is printing out those 'weird' values.

Comment: @MikeKobit thank you very much.  This is great information.  I'm still working on the 'unit testing', if you have a moment take a look my comment at the bottom on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print an object, it simply prints the result of calling `toString()`. The default `toString()` implementation will return a string containing the class name and a representation of the hash code (see the `toString()` [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) for details). As others have indicated, you can improve things by overriding `toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return expenses + " " + employeeList;
}
```

Your problem is here:

```
totalExpenses += employee.getExpenses();
```

This will add the expenses of the children, but not the grandchildren. You want:

```
totalExpenses += employee.getTotalExpenses();
```

You also probably want `getTotalExpenses()` to depend on the `expenses` field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding the following to the Employee class will fix your problem

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   //return something sensible like the Employee Name
    return getEmployeeName();
}
```

Comment: This is great. Was **not expecting** that output. I am still having issues with my **unit test** but have made some improvements. [pic](http://screencast.com/t/CkOSJEfjJE) , you will notice **assertEquals()** has changed, test still fails but 'Failure Trace' now reads correctly. I think there must being something incorrect with **getTotalExpenses()**